# Convert List<List<Integer>> to int[][] in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am looking to convert the `List<List<Integer>>` into `int[][]` in Java 8. Any quick pointers?

I tried something like below, but I need `int[][]`.

```
List<Integer> flat = arr.stream()
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map to int the inner lists and collect them into int arrays, then collect the outer list as a 2D array:

```
int[][] flat = arr.stream()
        .map(a -> a.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: Interesting to note that `arr` is not an ideal name for a `List<List<Integer>>`

Comment: Very nice +1, difficult to remember though! :)